# Are Yukawa interaction theories still in use?

Tags: nuclear-physics, interactions, strong-force, effective-field-theory, pions

As is commonly known, the [Yukawa interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction) (scalar/pseudoscalar) was used to describe the old-school, pion mediated, strong force, long before the discovery of quarks.

The theory has been proven to be **fundamentally** false. Some toy-theories exist, but that's another question.
Do they serve any function in the current era, in which case there is something fundamentally false?
If so, then what's its function?

Comment: Yukawa couples two fermions to scalar (for instance) and it is used in SM in Higgs scouplings, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction (section about Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking)

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov Does the fact that this theory is used in the SM in Higgs couplings imply that there maybe exists a deeper (more fundamental) explanation for the weak force (one with massless "gluons")? I know the Higgs field is supposed to give mass to all particles (including the Higgs) mass, but I have the feeling the arguments involved are circular. What do you think?

Comment: Higgs couplings are very small (for instance, quarks obtain mass dynamically via gluons, not Higgs), neutrino does not have mass in GWS, therefore I believe that more fundamental theory will come. In GWS Higgs field has non-zero vacuum value and we expand around this vacuum. Couplings to this vacuum value via Yukawa cause mass of particles. It does not seem circular for me but I am not an expert in GWS and SM

Comment: So you agree that a more fundamental law will someday see the light of day?

Comment: Why not? It seems that GWS will be a part of more general model

Comment: Could that be the Rishon Model: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Proton-and-Neutron-Rishon-Model-structure_fig2_312032100  or  https://www.google.com/search?q=rishon+model&rlz=1C1NDCM_nlNL744NL744&sxsrf=ACYBGNRsX9722pIMrjKI03wKJVfWdE1O0g:1579046218272&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=jFDSOg_kYVYx2M%253A%252CT4zfLjIr7YxOBM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQORtqck6BRpdeoMYnn8bYgEBqUIA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE67HHpYTnAhUHbFAKHVlDBYAQ9QEwAXoECAgQBQ#imgrc=Fck04SNVsQayeM:&vet=1

Comment: I avoid any speculative papers, ideas or theories. This model is the very first attempt  to explain phenomena in SM. I assume that if more general theory is created, it will be much more complicated. Now it is the end of discussion.